# Can I configure a Azure's key vault secret per service principal?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I'm used to use GCP's secret manager. There, we can create a secret and give a specific READ permission for one specific service account.
I mean, let's say we create a secret ABC and a service account "getsecretaccount", I can give the read permission for this SA called getsecretaccount to access the ABC secret. This getsecretaccount will not have access to any other secret there.

Can I achieve this scenario in Azure Key Vault?

Thx!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Authorization**

Key vault offer two different Authorizations: older *Vault access policy* and newer *Azure role-based access control*

[image: access control method selection on portal]

**Vault access policy**

BrunoLucasAzure already explained how this works. Personally I don't recommend using vault access policy unless you have some specific reason to use it:

- resource re-deployment will reset existing authorization defined in key vault properties. ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.keyvault/vaults?pivots=deployment-language-bicep#resource-format

  - passing [] to `accessPolicies` will clear access policy list
  - passing null or not using `accessPolicies` in template will generate error
  - of course you can read value of `accessPolicies`before re-deployment and then re-use existing value when re-deploying resource. TBH that kind of hacks should not be required by resource.

For more information: https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/key-vault/general/assign-access-policy-portal

**Azure role-based access control**

Azure role-based access control based key vault authorization uses Azure RBAC assignments for key vault data layer access control.

There is multiple ready-made RBAC roles for key vault data layer:

- Key Vault Administrator
- Key Vault Secrets Officer
- Key Vault Secrets User
- Key Vault Reader
- etc

Documentation only mentions thins `Azure RBAC for key vault also provides the ability to have separate permissions on individual keys, secrets, and certificates`
**=> you can add RBAC roles into individual key/secret/certificate**

Note that key/secret/certificate must be created before you can add RBAC to it.

[image: secret level RBAC on portal]

For more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/rbac-guide?tabs=azure-cli

**The answer**

You can use both methods:

- if you use older vault access policy, you need to create one key vault per service principal
- if you use RBAC based access control, you can manage access control on individual secret level

Comment: Awesome! role-based access control was what I waas looking for! If we create the key vault rbac, when I click in the secret I can choose which SPN, user and its role... can access the secret. one-to-one.

Answer (score -1):

if you have 1 azure vault with multiple secrets and you create an access policy for a user and select permission like "get" and/or "list", that user will be able to see all secrets under that vault. no option for separated permission per individual secret

[image]

[image]